# Can a 6 volt relay coil bear more than 6 volt?

Tags: pcb, sensor, pcb-design

I am using a 6 volt relay in H-bridge and controlling it with a 9 volt battery linked with a 2n2222 transistor (which is used as a switch and getting 5 volts via a low value  base resistor to get into the saturation region (fully on mode)). Once transistor turns on then a little voltage drop is appears at CE of transistor. Around 8 volt is fed into 6 volt relay coil. I am feeding 8V into the relay coil, why it is not burning or getting coil damage? Would low duty cycle operation be allowable? Could coil heating soften plastic parts of the relay? Should I employ a series resistor to be safe?

Comment: Did you take a look at the datasheet?

Comment: Not even going to try to decode that. Add a schematic.

Comment: Check the datasheet. Most relay's will have a "Max Voltage" rating expressed as a % of the normal working voltage. Typically this will be 120% to 180%.

Comment: If it's one of those little 9V PP3 batteries, by he time the relay's hot enough to fail, the battery will be down to 6V anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A '6v' relay is guaranteed to close at 6v, and to tolerate 6v continuously applied at an ambient temperature within its specification.

If you apply more than 6v to a 6v relay, it will get hotter than intended.

For a modest overload, like 8v, the only problem will be excess temperature rise, and that takes time to occur. A few seconds is unlikely to overheat the coil.

You have several unknowns.

1) How hot can the windings get before damage occurs, so insulation smoking on the wires, or plastic assemblies deforming as they get to softening temperatures?
2) How long will it take to get that hot?
3) Will they ever get that hot with 8v and your maximum ambient temperature?

Obviously the relay manufacturer is not going to warrant any of these, so it's up to you to find out by experiment. If you have two identical relays, then you could test one to destruction, and use the other. If you have only one, are you feeling lucky, punk?

Comment: I would expect the manufacturer to provide a data sheet with the voltage range over which the relay will work without damage.  It wouldn't surprise me if the relay could handle voltages in excess of 8V.

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to the particular datasheet for your relay, from the manufacturer. You also need to take into account the operating conditions that you are designing for (maximum ambient temperature in particular).

The heating at 8V vs 6V is nominally 77% more (it won't be quite that much because the coil increases in resistance as it heats). That's because power is proportional to voltage squared for resistance constant.

A typical small relay might be rated to withstand 130% of nominal voltage at maximum 70 degrees C, which is 7.8V. If the ambient never got that hot 8V would be just okay.

If you want maximum reliability its best to stay away from the maximum ratings, so I would suggest putting the resistor in there as good practice, provided there are no other considerations.

Answer (score 1):

Find the manufacturer's datasheet for the relay - the manufacturer's name and part number are normally printed on the case.  This will indicate the maximum voltage it is designed to handle.

There is normally quite a wide tolerance on relay coils, so it's quite likely that a 6V relay will handle 8V without problems.

Answer (score 1):

As always, manufacturers specify things in a simplistic way which, when it comes to driving them, actually means very little.

The truth of the matter is a relay is a current driven device, not voltage. The manufacturer specifies it by voltage because it's easier for laymen to understand and apply that way.

Basically what they are telling you is **the device is guaranteed to draw enough current at 6V to operate and not have thermal run-away under normal operating conditions.**

In truth you could pulse the coil and it would withstand hundreds if not thousands of volts before the insulation will fail as long as the average current does not exceed the some maximum current value.

Relays seldom mention a maximum current though.

Sometimes it's just a simple matter of hooking it up and seeing, or rather feeling, if it gets hot to the touch. But generally, the manufacturers  are trying to sell the *"LOW ACTIVATION CURRENT"* feature, so the over-heating part usually has lots of headroom. 50% over voltage is often acceptable at 25C, but check the specs for your particular device.

Here is a typical from Omron

[image]

From that information you can figure that this device's maximum current in the 5V model is 79.4 * 1.7 = 135mA. (Which is what you should get at 8.5V)

If you are concerned, I suggest you turn your driver into a current driver instead of a simple switch. Possibly PWM since you mention a battery. At which point you could also consider cutting back the current to a holding level once the relay has been activated.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not a good idea.  The limiting factor of relay coil current is heat.  Note that the power going into the coil, and therefore dissipated as heat, goes with the square of the current at DC.  That's because a relay coil looks mostly like a resistor at DC.

Not only might you overheat the relay, but you will be draining the 9 V battery faster than you need.  Those batteries already have relatively poor energy density.

What you can do is run the relay with PWM.  I'd use around 24 kHz frequency or so.  That is high enough so that you won't hear any whining.  It should also be high enough so that the coil current doesn't change much in any one cycle.  That will reduce heating in the coil, and reduce the current the battery has to put out.

Let's say after the drop in the battery and across the resistor, you get 8.5 V.  71% PWM duty cycle will give the relay a average of 6 V from your 9 V battery.  At 25 kHz PWM frequency, for example, that would be 35.3 µs on and 14.7 µs off.  Those are still "long" times relative to what you should be able to switch at decent transistor at.

Don't forget to put a Schottky diode in reverse across the relay coil.  Not only will that keep the transistor from getting fried by the inductive kickback, but it will keep the existing current circulating during the PWM off phase.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do.  Measure Rcoil (or look it up) and calculate the current needed to drive the coil (Icoil=6V/Rcoil).  Use the NPN transistor as a current sink.  Connect the 5V control signal directly to the NPN transistor's base, then put a current-setting resistor between the transistor's emitter and ground.  Assume the collector and emitter currents are equal, and the base-emitter voltage is 0.7V.  Ic=(5-Vbe)/Re  .  If you have a 50mA relay coil, then you would need 86 -> 82 ohm (5%) resistor.  The power dissopated in the resistor P=I*V is 0.215W, so I would go with an 82-ohm 1/2 watt emitter resistor for long life.

Don't forget to put a protection diode (cathode on 9V, anode on transistor collector) across the relay coil to clamp inductive kick, or your transistor will not last long.